# Latex listings for Fortran continuation label

Tags: listings, code

I would like to style the Fortran continuation label in the 6th column.

Currently, I have

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}

\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{listings}

\definecolor{codegreen}{rgb}{0,0.6,0}
\definecolor{codegray}{rgb}{0.5,0.5,0.5}
\definecolor{codepurple}{rgb}{0.58,0,0.82}
\definecolor{backcolour}{rgb}{0.95,0.95,0.92}

\lstset{ %
    backgroundcolor=\color{backcolour},
    commentstyle=\color{codegreen},
    keywordstyle=\color{blue},
    numberstyle=\tiny\color{codegray},
    stringstyle=\color{codepurple},
    basicstyle=\scriptsize,
    breakatwhitespace=false,
    breaklines=true,
    captionpos=b,
    keepspaces=true,
    showspaces=false,
    showstringspaces=false,
    showtabs=false,
    tabsize=2
}

\begin{document}

\begin{lstlisting}[language={[77]Fortran}]
subroutine vumat (
c Read only -
     *     jblock, ndir, nshr, nstatev, nfieldv, nprops, lanneal,
     *     stepTime, totalTime, dt, cmname, coordMp, charLength,
     *     props, density, strainInc, relSpinInc,
     *     tempOld, stretchOld, defgradOld, fieldOld,
     *     stressOld, stateOld, enerInternOld, enerInelasOld,
     *     tempNew, stretchNew, defgradNew, fieldNew,
c Write only -
     *     stressNew, stateNew, enerInternNew, enerInelasNew )
\end{lstlisting}
\end{document}
```

[image]

I would like to have a green background of those continuation symbols, similar to
[image]

Please instruct me. Thank you!

Comment: You might want to read the document for `literate=[*]⟨replacement item⟩ . . . ⟨replacement item⟩` syntax.